# Guardar cambios de un commit anterior y suplantarlo por el commit actual

Tags: git

Tengo en una `branch` el ultimo commit con errores ya pusheado a `gitlab`, donde posteriormente me di cuenta que tenia errores, por lo cual volvi de manera local a un commit anterior donde todo estaba ok (para ello realice `git checkout hash`)

Ahora realice modificaciones en ese commit anterior.

Como hago para guardar los cambios y a su vez hacer que ese commit sea el ultimo, luego pushearlo y todo esto sin crear rama nueva?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La forma más sencilla de proceder es jugar con el branch pointer de `HEAD` (con un soft reset), colocándolo en el commit que está malo, hacer un commit amend y luego colocar la rama en el commit resultante.

```
git reset --soft el-branch
git add .
git commit --amend --no-edit
# si te gusta el resultado, pon el-branch aquí
git branch -f el-branch
```

Y ahora puedes proceder a hacer un force-push al remoto.

Comment: Muchas gracias, sirvio, pero me quedo en head detached hash, como podria arreglarlo?

Comment: `git checkout el-branch`, dado que `el-branch` está en el commit apropiado.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes desde la rama donde está el commit utilizar
para anadir los cambios de los archivos que necesites que esten en el commit

```
git add .
```

luego utiliza el siguiente comando para actualizar el commit con esos cambio

```
git commit --amend
```

y ya quedarás con un solo commit, pero con las últimas modificaciones, y para hacer push a la rama si está en gitlab puedes utilizar el siguiente para que sobre escriba el commit en gitlab

```
git push --force
```